# Add sep paramter in map_dfr read.delim function

Tags: r, purrr

I have the following code

How can I tell this function that my CSV has a ^ delimiter rather than comma?

```
list_of_files <-   dir_ls(path = "Folder/Test")

a <- list_of_files %>% 
  map_dfr(.f = read.delim2
          , .id="Sample")
```

but get an error when I add parameters to the read.delim2(sep = "^")

```
list_of_files <-   dir_ls(path = "Folder/Test")

a <- list_of_files %>% 
  map_dfr(.f = read.delim2(sep = "^"), .id="Sample")
```

`Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, :  argument "file" is missing, with no default`

How can I tell this function that my CSV has a ^ delimiter rather than comma?

Thank you

Edit: Added code showing error.
I would also like to add other paramteres to read.delim2 such as "skip = 8" for each file im reading

Comment: Please show the code that leads to the error and provide sample input.

Comment: done @G.Grothendieck

Comment: `read.delim(sep = "^")` is not a function.  Use `~ read.delim2(.x, sep = "^")`

Answer (score 0):

Okay - so I learned that the function used within map, parameters are just left in the map function. like below

map_dfr(.f = read.delim2, .id="Sample", sep = "^", skip = 8)